# Using pandas to plot data

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to stackoverflow. My data frame is similar to the one given below. I want to plot this data such that I can get a plot for `A`'s activity, `B`'s activity and `C`'s activity separately.

How can I accomplish this using pandas?

```
Name    Date           Activity
A       01-02-2015       1
A       01-03-2015       2
A       01-04-2015       3
A       01-04-2015       1
B       01-02-2015       1
B       01-02-2015       2
B       01-03-2015       1
B       01-04-2015       5
C       01-31-2015       1
```

Comment: `pandas` has a really nice documentation. See here some examples on [visualization](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another method would include `pivot`. Starting from your dataframe `df`, I would set the index to `Date`:

```
df = df.set_index('Date')
```

and then pivot the table according to your values:

```
d = pd.pivot_table(df,index=df.index, columns='Name', values='Activity').fillna(0)
```

This returns this structure:

```
Name        A    B  C
Date                 
2015-01-02  1  1.5  0
2015-01-03  2  1.0  0
2015-01-04  2  5.0  0
2015-01-31  0  0.0  1
```

And in base of your needs you can simply plot it with:

```
d.plot()
```

Actually you have some duplicate values in the example, but now the plot looks like the following. Hope that helps.

[image]

Comment: Is there anyway to create sub data frame for each A, B and C

Answer (score 0):

Use [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html). There you can use:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure()
plt.plot(df.ix[df.Name == 'A', ['Date', 'Activity']])
plt.plot(df.ix[df.Name == 'B', ['Date', 'Activity']])
plt.plot(df.ix[df.Name == 'C', ['Date', 'Activity']])
plt.show()
```

Assuming `df` is your pandas `DataFrame`

Comment: maybe `plt.plot(df.ix[df.Name == 'A', ['Date', 'Activity']])`?

Comment: eeeh you're right! When I answered the df code window in OP's question was plain text so I didn't notice and couldn't edit it either bc there were pending edits... corrected!